# SQL: JOIN Syntax Variation

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am using PostgreSQL, but I think the question applies to other SQLs as well.

I was editing a `JOIN` clause, and I ended up with the following syntax.

```
tableA JOIN tableB JOIN tableC ON tableB.fk = tableC.pk ON tableA.pk = tableB.fk;
```

That is, I have 2 JOIN clauses followed by 2 ON clauses. The fields `fk` and `pk` are my primary keys, abbreviated for this example.

I tested before I noticed the syntax. What surprised me is that it worked.

The question is: is that a proper variation of the syntax, and how is it interpreted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is legal, though not common.

To interpret it, work from the inside out. First evaluate `tableB JOIN tableC`, and use the first `ON` expression. It helps, because this part makes sense all by itself:

```
tableB JOIN tableC ON tableB.fk = tableC.pk
```

The *entire result set* from that expression then becomes the 2nd-term/right-hand-side for the outer join expression, giving you this:

```
tableA JOIN (previous expression) ON tableA.pk = tableB.fk
```

One thing to remember is that if any records were filtered by the first/inner expression, they are not considered at all for the outer expression. It makes no difference in this example, but it can change things when OUTER joins are involved.

Comment: Thanks. That was my guess, but I’ve had no experience with that particular form. It’s certainly not what I wrote: It sort of happened when I had an old view reverse engineered.

Comment: To confirm this, I reorganised the `FROM` clause as follows: `FROM tableA JOIN tableB  ON tableA.pk = tableB.fk JOIN tableC ON tableB.fk = tableC.pk;`, which is more normal. I got the same results.

Answer (score 3):

What you have written is correct. You can also write it as :

```
tableA JOIN tableB ON tableA.pk = tableB.fk JOIN tableC ON tableB.fk = tableC.pk
```

Both the queries gives the same result though :)